# its about LISP program, common lisp

Tags: lisp

can u pls help me guys, its a tutorial question given to us by our lecturer & we can't actually seem to crack it no matter how much we tried. plz help

```
; perform some type/error checking,
;    then call function h to ....

(defun f (L N)
   (cond
       ( (not (listp L) ) nil)
       ( (not (integerp N) ) nil)
       ( (< N 1) nil)
       ( (< (length L) N) nil)
       (t (h L N '() ) )
   )
)

(defun h (L N Acc)
   (cond
       ( (eq N 1) (append Acc (cdr L) ) )
       (t (h (cdr L) (- N 1) (append Acc (list (car L) ) ) ) )
   )
)
```

1. For the function call `(f '(1 2 3) 1)` show the sequence of calls (if any) made to function `h`, and show the final value returned by function `f`.
2. For the function call `(f '(1 2 3 4) 3)` show the sequence of calls (if any) made to function `h`, and show the final value returned by function `f`.
3. If we observe that function `f` appears to carry out some basic type/error checking and then calls function h to do the "real" work, what is it that `h` actually accomplishes?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Can you please edit your question and ask a question? And add information what kind of Lisp is this about, Common Lisp, Scheme...? Also please keep in mind SO is not "do my homework" site.

Comment: Hlw.. Its actually not a home work, its common lisp.. Read/comprehending.. Understanding lisp function.

Comment: did you try `trace` it? `(trace f h)`?

Comment: No I ddnt.  Bt I will shortly. Tanx

Answer (score 0):

### General remarks

- You cannot assume [`EQ`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_eq.htm) will work reliably with numbers, according to the specification. Since `N` is a number, you should use [`=`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_eq_sle.htm) instead.
- The [`COND`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/m_cond.htm) in `H` has only two possible outcomes; that may be rewritten with an [`IF`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/s_if.htm).
- Do not add spaces between parentheses, do not let parentheses alone on a line. Please follow the usual formatting of Lisp forms (see for example http://lisp-lang.org/style-guide).
- The overuse of [`APPEND`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_append.htm) in `H` is making the code more complex than it should be.

### Function F

```
(defun f (L N)
   (cond
       ( (not (listp L) ) nil)
       ( (not (integerp N) ) nil)
       ( (< N 1) nil)
       ( (< (length L) N) nil)
       (t (h L N '() ) )
   )
)
```

Function `F` calls `H` only when the code reaches the clauses guarded by T, which happens only when all the previous test fails.
Let's invert all tests to simplify a little bit, and use [`WHEN`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/m_when_.htm).
The equivalent form is:

```
(defun f (list number)
  (when (and (listp list)
             (integerp number)
             (<= 1 number (length list)))
    (h list number)))
```

The third argument to `h` is omitted, because we do not need it.

### Function H

```
(defun h (L N Acc)
   (cond
       ( (eq N 1) (append Acc (cdr L) ) )
       (t (h (cdr L) (- N 1) (append Acc (list (car L) ) ) ) )
   )
)
```

The code is using [`APPEND`](http://www.lispworks.com/reference/HyperSpec/Body/f_append.htm) at each step of recursion. The accumulator might have been added to make the function tail-recursive, or maybe just to obfuscate the intent. You could rewrite `H` without the auxiliary list to better understand what it does:

```
(defun h (list number)
  (if (= number 1)
      (cdr list)
      (cons (car list)
            (h (cdr list) (- number 1)))))
```

And some tests:

```
(f '(a b c d e f) 3)
=> (A B D E F)

(f '(a b c d e f) 2)
=> (A C D E F)
```

Comment: @MuhammerdMujiyb No problem, hope it helps